# Script not loading in webview (Xaml/C#) windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

This is the code i used in both Windows store app and windows phone app to embed the html into webview.
It's working in windows store app but not in the phone app.

```
<WebView x:Name="game" Source="ms-appx-web:///Folder/index.html" Grid.Row="0" Loaded="webview_loaded"/>
```

This is the html code in index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

By going back and forth I found that the script.js is loading in windows phone app. Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Anybody solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is disabled by default on Windows Phone webbrowsers. Try to set IsScriptEnabled="true" on your webbrowser.

Comment: IsScriptEnabled is not available on WP8.1, since its using a WebView like W8.1 and not Webbrowser like on WP8.0

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the Build Action property of the file in the solution explorer set to Content.

Comment: how did that help..? I tried to set build action to content but that is giving me exceptions for all UI controls I've set on that page.